# IE issue with input type submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer

Not getting `name` of input type `submit` in `$_POST` array after submitting form.

```
<input type="submit" name="approve" id="approve" value="Approve" class="btnSty" onclick="fnHideTextArea(); return fnRa1Validation();" >
```

(in `fnRa1Validation()` form get submitted and control goes to another page,
I did alert for `approve` id's value and getting proper value before submit.)

after submit, I print `$_POST` and unable to find `approve` in IE10/9.

Working fine with firefox and chrome.

here is function.

```
fnRa1Validation()
{
   // Some basic validations goes here...

   document.getElementById("page_action").value="Ra1Request";

   document.frmPost.action='manage_travel_expense_request.php';

   //alert(document.getElementById("approve").name);

  document.frmPost.submit();

}
```

need help.

Comment: post your function fnRa1Validation()

Comment: Have you tried moving the JavaScript code into the form tag? `<form onsubmit="...">`

Comment: @Ja͢ck yes. not working but.

Comment: @Ja͢ck can not move code to `<form onsubmit="...">` and remove it from current `onclick`. form is to big.

Comment: Try to return true in fnRa1Validation function

Answer (score 1):

```
      <html>

      <form name="contactform" method="post" action="check.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                   <input type="submit" name="approve" id="approve" value="Approve"       class="btnSty" onclick="fnHideTextArea(); return fnRa1Validation();" >

                   </form>

       <script>
         function fnHideTextArea()
         {
          alert("welcome");
         }
       </script>
```

This is working in IE.try this

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not work for `submit` unless the form that is being submitted has been added to DOM.

So, you need to add a trick.

Add a wrapper div `post-form` to the form and on click of that `div`, fire the form's `submit` event.

```
$(".post-form").click(function(e) {
```